# How to do a Regex Replace for this text?

Tags: c#, regex

How to do a regex replace for this text:

```
    <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Request Block Host</span> to

    `<u>Request Block Host</u>`
```

So far, I have this, assume "text" is the complete string that has the above tag.

```
   text = Regex.Replace(text, "<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">.*?</span>", delegate(Match mContent)
        {
            return mContent.Value.Replace("<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">", "<u>").Replace("</span>", "</u>");
        }, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Do you really think regex is the best tool for this job? Wouldn't Html Agility Pack (or at least an xml parser) be more appropriate?

Comment: I use linq for most of my parsing, for this, I prefer Regex.Replace if there is an easy solution out there. Let me know. Feel free to give an idea using xml parser as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, 
    "<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">(.*?)</span>", 
    "<u>$1</u>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); // <u>Request Block Host</u>
```

This will match a literal `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">`, followed by zero or more of any character, captured in group 1, followed by a literal `</span>`. It will replace the matched text with `<u>`, followed by the contents of group 1, followed by a literal `</u>`.

Comment: @user2085236 The `(.*?)` in the pattern is a group. Since it's the first group that appears, it's referred to as group 1. `$1` in the replacement string represents the contents of group 1, so the output will be whatever was captured in that group surrounded by a `<u>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _string = "<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Request Block Host</span>";

var text = Regex.Replace(_string, "<.+>(.*)</.+>", "<u>$1</u>");
```

:D

Comment: `Regex.Replace(code, "<\.\+>\(\.\*\)</\.\+>", "<span [^>]+underline[^>]+>([^<]*?)</span[^>]+>");` :D

Comment: I don't believe it needs to escape each character... I ran your example in LinqPad, results were not good...

Comment: Steiner - Thanks ,however, yours might not work because there are multiple <.+> like <b>, <font> etc in my string. I am already replacing them by different means and so, dont want to do a bulk <.+> for everything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @quetzalcoatl 's point was that your pattern is *far* too broad. It will match any opening tag followed by any closing tag, and very greedily at that.

Comment: p.s.w.g - I am trying to test this, what does '$1 mean. I want to replace with whatever text I have b/w those tags. In my case, with "Request Block Host". So, that is my question, how would I replace to  <u>Request Block Host</u>

Comment: All good.  I follow the "broad questions; broad answers" rule.  Wasn't aware you needed it precisely for that string instance.

Comment: @Steiner: maybe my joke was a little too obscure. Take your code as a string/text and run it through the line I provided. Unless I've got a typo somewhere, it will replace your regex in your comment to a better one. That's why the leftside is heavily escaped. As p.s.w.g properly noticed, your original search patter is _far too broad_. With input other than the provided short example, it has a great chance of crossing the tag boundary and eating up tons of characters - completely not what was desired. I've just added blocks against that. The rightpart of my snippet is direct, check it.

Comment: BTW. now I see I have a typo: the expression should end with `</span[^>]*>` not `</span[^>]+>`

Comment: @quetzalcoatl 
Honestly, I answered the way I did because no such constraints were specific.  Also, I just presumed it was a one-off quick search, not an entire page; because I don't comprehend why someone would want to use a deprecated `<u>` element versus the standard style and text-decoration. [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/graphics.html#edef-U)